# notserializableexception for an object whose class implements Serializable

Tags: java, serialization

I have this class

```
public class wordObject implements java.io.Serializable
    {
        String wordName;
        int occCount;
        int count;
        HashMap<Integer, Double> lineDict;
        int[] mat;

        public wordObject(String name,int num)
        {
            wordName = name;
            occCount=1;
            count = num;
            lineDict=new HashMap<Integer,Double>(lineC);
            mat = new int[lineC];

        }

    }
```

But when I try to write an instance of the class to the disk using a piece of code as given below

```
public static writeObj(WordObject obj)
    FileOutputStream f_out = new FileOutputStream(loc);

            // Write object with ObjectOutputStream
            ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream (f_out);

            // Write object out to disk,obj is instance of wordObject
            obj_out.writeObject ( obj );
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: searchTAemd
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
```

Any help will be most welcome.

EDIT: I have checked that HashMap already implements serializable.

Comment: is `obj` an object of type `wordObject`? The error says it came from `searchTAemd`

Comment: this looks perfectly serializable. Are you sure that the obj is an instance of wordObject.

Comment: I've just tested this with obj = new wordObject("foo", 3); it works without error... obj must be referencing another type which isn't serializable.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes `obj` is of type `wordObject`, `searchTAemd` is the name of the class in which all this code is placed.

Comment: Where does the variable `lineC` come from?  The parent class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `wordObject` is an inner class, and an inner class always holds an implicit reference to its outer class, you cannot serialize an inner class unless the outer class is also serializable. Actually it's not even recommended to try;

From the [serialization specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539);

> Serialization of inner classes (i.e., nested classes that are not
>   static member classes), including local and anonymous classes, is
>   strongly discouraged for several reasons. Because inner classes
>   declared in non-static contexts contain implicit non-transient
>   references to enclosing class instances, serializing such an inner
>   class instance will result in serialization of its associated outer
>   class instance as well.

Answer (score -3):

When doing serialization, all objects that your object can reach (ie its member variables and the members of its members etc etc) must be serializable, or you get this exception. This is common problem with object serialization

Comment: What part of his class are you saying is not Serializable?

Comment: From the class definition of wordObject, all the fields are serializable.