# Service Loader implementations needing default public constructors

Tags: java, static, constructor, externalizable

I was trying to understand how in Java Service Loader works? I came across this [blog](http://technotes.tostaky.biz/2013/03/java-serviceloader-example.html):

Could you please help me understand why the author claims:

> The implementation must have a public parameterless constructor.

Okay I get the first part. Now a follow up question. I can post it as a follow up a question but thought it
would be better to have it as part of the same question.

Consider the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1-110-F.2):

It says:

> In addition, the constructor of a non-private inner member class must be compiled such that it has as its first parameter, an additional implicit parameter representing the immediately enclosing instance (§8.1.3).

So does that mean I cannot externalize a inner class. Please consider the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

class Y {
  class ABC {
    ABC() {
      System.out.println("ABC Constructor");
    }
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out)
      throws IOException {
      System.out.println("ABC.writeExternal");
    }
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in)
      throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
      System.out.println("ABC.readExternal");
    }
  }

  public void foo() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Constructing objects:");
    ABC abc = new ABC();
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(
    new FileOutputStream("InnerClass.out"));
    System.out.println("Saving objects:");
    o.writeObject(abc);
    o.close();
    // Now get them back:
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
      new FileInputStream("InnerClass.out"));
    System.out.println("Recovering abc:");
    // OOPS! Throws an exception:
    abc = (ABC)in.readObject();
  }
}

public class InnerClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Hello World\n");
    Y y = new Y();
    System.out.println(y);
    y.foo();
  }  
}
```

It fails at runtime:

```
Hello World

Y@6bc7c054
Constructing objects:
ABC Constructor
Saving objects:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: Y$ABC
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at Y.foo(InnerClass.java:24)
    at InnerClass.main(InnerClass.java:40)
```

How can I use Externalize class ABC?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's required to create a new instance via reflection.

[I guess here's relevant code, line 362](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.java.html):

```
S p = service.cast(Class.forName(cn, true, loader).newInstance());
```

Thus it invokes "parameterless" constructor since [`Class.newInstance()` can only invoke the zero-argument constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html).

**Edit:**

Actually, it's not *required* to create a zero-argument constructor for `public class` unless you define another constructor.

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html):

> > You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.

So, the following code is perfectly correct:

```
public final class MyServiceImpl implements MyService { 
    @Override
    public long getTime() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    } 
}
```

Default constructor for `MyServiceImpl`  will be the same as:

```
public MyServiceImpl() { }
```

Since `MyServiceImpl` [is a public class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> > if the class is declared public, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier public

Thus constructor in `MyServiceImpl` is redundant.

My guess is that author of the blog post just wanted to make sure that `ServiceLoader` will be able to instantiate *service provider* even when it contains some explicit constructors with arguments.

---

**Conclusion:** *Service provider* **should** have explicit no-argument constructor only if it contains explicit constructors with arguments. Default constructor will suffice otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have edited my question with one more part. 

Thanks

Comment: @gudge Currently, I have nothing to add to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9999476/2286990). Is it helpful for you?

Comment: @gudge But, [in general](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), inner class may be instantiated like that: `OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have accepted your answer. The first part is absolutely clear. The second is not. How do we deserialize a non-static inner class. 

Thanks.

Comment: Well, class should implement marker interface `Serializable`([or `Externalizable`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/818093/2286990)) in order to have possibility to be serializable/deserializable  thus both inner and outer classes should implement `Serializable` but it's not recommended([see answer I mentioned in my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9999476/2286990)). So you _may_ implement Serializable like that `class Y implements Serializable` and `class ABC implements Serializable` but it's not a good idea at all. I'm, personally, trying to avoid inner classes in my code.

Comment: After reading 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539 (Note - Serialization of inner classes) things are much clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can read the reason on official  [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)

> The only requirement enforced by this facility is that provider classes must have a zero-argument constructor so that they can be instantiated during loading.

If you declared a constructor with parameter you can not use it properly. 
Read this [article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/serviceloader_load_service.htm) with example

Answer (score 1):

Many techniques require a parameterless constructor, so an instance can be created. If there are only constructors that require parameters, the mechanism doesn't know what to pass.

A notable exception to this is the serialization mechanism, which doesn't require a no-param constructor, but that is only because it has some added "magic help" from the VM.